# My Auth Context Provider state variables are not updating until a full refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I have an Auth Context Provider that holds state variables for token and role and a login and logout function.  I can't get the logout function to work.  After I click a link that calls the logout function, I can still navigate to a protected page.  And I console out the role and token and it still shows them as populated.  After I do a refresh, it then wipes them out and forces me to login.

Here is my useAuth.js:

```js
import { createContext, useContext, useMemo } from 'react';
import { useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useSessionStorage } from './useSessionStorage';
import { authenticateUser } from '../utils/APIFunctions';

const AuthContext = createContext(undefined);

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [token, setToken] = useSessionStorage('token', null);
    const [role, setRole] = useSessionStorage('userRole', null);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    const login = async (data) => {
        const password = data.password;
        const navigateTo = data.navigateTo;
        const roles = data.roles;
        // check this password in the DB
        let error = '';
        const result = await authenticateUser(password);

        const authLevel = result?.data[0]?.auth_level;
        let theRole;
        switch (authLevel) {
            case 99:
                theRole = 'SuperAdmin';
                break;
            case 1:
                theRole = 'User';
                break;
            case 2:
                theRole = 'Admin';
                break;
            case 3:
                theRole = 'Regulator';
                break;
            case 4:
                theRole = 'QC';
                break;
            default:
                theRole = 'none';
        }
        setRole(theRole);
        if (result?.status === 200 && authLevel > 0) {
            // this is a valid password
            if (roles.includes(theRole)) {
                // they are allowed to access the page they are attempting to access
                const time = Date.now();
                setToken({ token: password + '-' + time });
                navigate(navigateTo);
            } else {
                // show unauthorized message/page
                error = 'You do not have access to this page.';
            }
        } else {
            if (result.data.name === 'ConnectionError') {
                error = 'Unable to connect to database.';
            } else if (result?.data?.ReturnValue === 0) {
            } else {
                error = 'Error logging into Scheduler.';
            }
        }
        return error;
    };

    const logout = (redirect = true) => {
        sessionStorage.clear();
        setToken(null);
        setRole(null);
        if (redirect) {
            navigate('/', { replace: true });
        }
        location.reload();  // i would like to remove this, the hard refresh causes a white page until the app reloads
    };

    const value = useMemo(
        () => ({
            token,
            role,
            login,
            logout,
        }),
        [token, role]
    );

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={value}>
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};

export const useAuth = () => {
  return useContext(AuthContext);
};
```

And then my ProtectedRoute.js that checks and verifies the token and role:

```js
import { Navigate, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuth } from '../../hooks/useAuth';
import { Roles } from './Roles';

export const ProtectedRoute = ({ children, roles }) => {
    const { token, role } = useAuth();
    console.log({ token, role });
    const location = useLocation();

    if (
        !token ||
        (!roles.includes(Roles.Everyone) && !roles.includes(role))
    ) {
        // user is not authenticated
        return (
            <Navigate
                to={'/login'}
                state={{ from: location, roles }} // <-- pass in route state
                replace
            />
        );
    }
    return children;
};
```

Here is useSessionStorage.js:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

export const useSessionStorage = (keyName, defaultValue) => {
    const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(() => {
        try {
            const value = window.sessionStorage.getItem(keyName);

            if (value) {
                return JSON.parse(value);
            } else {
                if (defaultValue) {
                    window.sessionStorage.setItem(
                        keyName,
                        JSON.stringify(defaultValue)
                    );
                }
                return defaultValue;
            }
        } catch (err) {
            return defaultValue;
        }
    });

    const setValue = (newValue) => {
        if (newValue) {
            try {
                window.sessionStorage.setItem(
                    keyName,
                    JSON.stringify(newValue)
                );
            } catch (err) {}
            setStoredValue(newValue);
        }
    };

    return [storedValue, setValue];
};
```

Comment: Can you share the code for `useSessionStorage`?

Comment: can you make sure `logout` function is actually called. maybe add a console statement to see if it is called

Comment: The `setValue` returned by `useSessionStorage` explicitly ignores `newValue` if it is null. Maybe amend the function to `removeItem` for that case, and move `setStoredValue(newValue)` outside the `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update the code for `setValue` in `useSessionStorage()` so that it correctly handles falsey values.

May depend on your particular use case but something like:

```js
    const setValue = (newValue) => {
        if (newValue) {
            try {
                window.sessionStorage.setItem(
                    keyName,
                    JSON.stringify(newValue)
                );
            } catch (err) {}
        }
        else {
            window.sessionStorage.removeItem(keyName);
        }

        setStoredValue(newValue);
    };
```

Comment: Holy smokes, that worked!  Thank you so much!